# Error with Headless selenium chrome driver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While running selenium chrome driver got the following error:

```
Error: Error connecting to customer repository: Could not start a new session. Unable to obtain: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 118.0, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --disable-gpu, disable-infobars, user-agent=amazon-xyz, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --no-sandbox], extensions: [], prefs: {profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting: 2, profile.default_content_setting_values: {images: 2}}}, goog:loggingPrefs: {performance: ALL}, pageLoadStrategy: eager, platformName: linux, se:noVncPort: 7900, se:vncEnabled: true, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept}, error Failed to parse json output, executed: [--browser, chrome, --output, json, --browser-version, 118.0] Build info: version: '4.14.1', revision: '03f8ede370' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.198-187.748.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.20.1' Driver info: driver.version: unknown Host info: host: 'xyz', ip: '127.0.0.1' Build info: version: '4.14.1', revision: '03f8ede370' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.198-187.748.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.20.1' Driver info: driver.version: unknown Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host: 'xyz', ip: '123.456.789.123', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.198-187.748.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.18' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver remote stacktrace: [{fileName=DriverServiceSessionFactory.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=apply, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory, lineNumber=238, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=DriverServiceSessionFactory.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=apply, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory, lineNumber=72, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=SessionSlot.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=apply, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot, lineNumber=147, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=LocalNode.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=newSession, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode, lineNumber=464, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=LocalDistributor.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=startSession, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor, lineNumber=644, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=LocalDistributor.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=newSession, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor, lineNumber=563, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=LocalDistributor.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=handleNewSessionRequest, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable, lineNumber=823, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=LocalDistributor.java, moduleVersion=null, moduleName=null, nativeMethod=false, methodName=lambda$run$1, className=org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable, lineNumber=783, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=ThreadPoolExecutor.java, moduleVersion=11.0.20.1, moduleName=java.base, nativeMethod=false, methodName=runWorker, className=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor, lineNumber=1128, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=ThreadPoolExecutor.java, moduleVersion=11.0.20.1, moduleName=java.base, nativeMethod=false, methodName=run, className=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker, lineNumber=628, classLoaderName=null}, {fileName=Thread.java, moduleVersion=11.0.20.1, moduleName=java.base, nativeMethod=false, methodName=run, className=java.lang.Thread, lineNumber=829, classLoaderName=null}]
```

Tried with new version but same error and no option on reducing the version